# C++ Search Performance

Tags: c++, performance, hash, full-text-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ Search Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079551/c-search-performance)

What I have is two text files. One contains a list of roughly 70,000 names (~1.5MB). The other contains text which will be obtained from miscellaneous sources. That is, this file's contents will change each time the program is executed (~0.5MB). Essentially, I want to be able to paste some text into a text file and see which names my list are found. Kind of like the find function (CTR + F) but with 70,000 keywords.

In any case, what I have thus far is:

```
 int main()
 {

 ifstream namesfile("names.txt");   //names list
 ifstream miscfile("misc.txt");     //misc text
 vector<string> vecnames;           //vector to hold names
 vector<string> vecmisc;            //vector to hold misc text
 size_t found;

 string s;
 string t;

 while (getline(namesfile,s))       
     vecnames.push_back(s);  

 while (getline(miscfile,t))        
     vecmisc.push_back(t);

 //outer loop iterates through names list
 for (vector<string>::size_type i = 0; i != vecnames.size(); ++i) {
     //inner loop iterates through the lines of the mist text file
     for (vector<string>::size_type j = 0;j != vecmisc.size(); ++j) {
         found=vecmisc[j].find(vecnames[i]);
         if (found!=string::npos) {
             cout << vecnames[i] << endl;
             break;
         }
     }
 }

 cout << "SEARCH COMPLETE";

 //to keep console application from exiting
 getchar();

 return 0;
 }
```

Now this works great as far as extracting the data I need, however, it is terribly slow and obviously inefficient since each name requires that I potentially search the entire file again which gives (75000 x # of lines in misc text file) iterations. If anyone could help, I would certainly appreciate it. Some sample code is most welcomed. Additionally, I'm using Dev C++ if that makes any difference.

It has been suggested that I implement a hash set on my data, however, I have no idea how to go about this. If anyone understands how I could apply this method I'd appreciate a start in the right direction. Sincere thanks.

Comment: Your code example lacks definition of veccomp and vectenk that you use in your code.

Comment: Please don't re-post the same question.  If you want to add more informmation then edit the original instead.

Comment: @finnw: damm didn't notice. I hope this doesn't get closed now, since I've gone and provided an implementation :)

Answer (score 4):

You could construct a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) from all the names and mark the nodes that are endpoints so you know when you have a match (or you could wait for a mismatch and emit the substring up to that point from the end of the last match). Then you try to match the input to the trie, one char at a time, and you should have O(n) performance.

```
trieRoot = preprocessedListOfNames

trieCursor = trieRoot
for each character in text
    if character in trieCursor.neighbors
        trieCursor = trieCursor.neighbors[character]
    else
        if matchSize > 1 and trieCursor.isEndpoint
            emit match
        trieCursor = trieRoot
```

If the name list is relatively static you could even pre-process it and store it so you don't have to construct it each time you want to do a search.

Comment: Also look up the radix trees. Basically a specialized form, though some code just uses the terms interchangeably.

Comment: I'd also like to suggest the [Aho–Corasick string matching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm), it's a specialization which falls back to the suffix of a node for failed matches, giving linear time searching.

Comment: Prefix, not suffix. (in case my comment made no sense)

Answer (score 2):

Change `vecnames` from a vector to a set.  Change its call to push_back to insert.  Then, instead of looping over it, just loop over `vecmisc` and call `vecnames.find(...)` to check if each input is one of the names.  This will turn your O(n m) system into O(n log m).  You could also use hash_set and achieve O(n) (which may or may not be much faster in practice).

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off reading the bigger file into memory; qsort()ing it; and then reading the second file line by line and bsearch()ing on each entry in that second file.

Answer (score 0):

You  could use a map/Associative-Array Data Structure from STL. A map doesn't necessarily store data in a linear fashion and hence a find operation generally takes less than linear time - ie - < O(n) .

For your case you can use a map of type - `map<string,bool>`.
example usage - http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/stl/stlmap.html

Replace `vector<string> vecmisc;` with `map<string,bool> vecmisc`.

```
for (vector<string>::size_type i = 0; i != vecnames.size(); ++i) {
 // No inner loop needed

     found=vecmisc.find(vecnames[i]);
     if (found!=string::npos) {
         cout << vecnames[i] << endl;
         break;
     }

 }
```

Comment: "A map doesn't _necessarily_ store data in a linear fashion"? A map does _necessarily not store data in a linear fashion_, this way it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

A number of slight improvements.

Benchmark before: <strike>7 minutes 56 second and counting (will update)</strike>
**Update**: finally finished in 15m25s, yielding a **performance increase of roughly 3000 x**

Benchmark after: **0.3? seconds** (see below for updated figures)

Code:

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>

template <class It> It readInto(std::istream& is, It OI);

std::set<std::string> readnames(const std::string& filename)
{
    std::string s;
    std::set<std::string> result;

    std::ifstream namesfile(filename.c_str());   //names list
    readInto(namesfile, std::inserter(result, result.end()));
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::set<std::string> vecnames = readnames("names.txt");

    //inner loop iterates through the lines of the mist text file
    std::ifstream miscfile("misc.txt");     //misc text
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(miscfile, line))
        if (vecnames.end() != vecnames.find(line))
            std::cout << line << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

// helper to read linewise into output iterator
template <class It> It readInto(std::istream& is, It OI)
{
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(is, line))
    {
        if (line.size()>0) // TODO you may want to trim/normalize these
            OI++ = line;
    }
    return OI;
}
```

Data:

$ cp /etc/dictionaries-common/words names.txt
   $ 
   $ wc names.txt misc.txt
      98569   98568  931708 names.txt
     166634  529910 4283592 misc.txt

This results in 151486 lines of output (which contain 3968 uniqe values, when inspected:)

```
$ ./t2 | wc -l
859

$ ./t2 | sort -u | wc -l
2
```

Because that is a pretty skewed benchmark, I benchmarked the other extreme as well:

```
$ cp names.txt misc.txt
$ time ./t | wc -l
98568

real    0m0.365s
user    0m0.372s
sys 0m0.228s
```

Tests performed with optimized builds on i386 (32bit) g++ 4.4.5, redirecting stdout to /dev/null and removing the `getchar()` call at the end

Comment: First off, I sincerely appreciate your help. Unfortunately, names are sometimes more than one word (i.e. John Paul Jr. III). That is, if this entire name is somewhere within the misc. text, then it should be sent to standard output. Whereas, with the above implementation all of the Johns, Pauls, Jrs, and IIIs which appear throughout the misc. text will also be sent to output. Any way to tweak this to make it work for this? Thanks again.

Comment: Simple. Go back to reading lines in a loop. **Just don't store them in vector for no reason**. I'll leave that as an exercise because it's dinner time :)

Comment: Cool. I'll try it out here shortly. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry to bother you about this still but I can't seem to get it to work correctly. I'm back to reading in each line as a string as suggested, however, I not all that familiar with iterators and can't figure out how to properly implement the find function.

Comment: @Dom Ok, I adapted for reading by lines. Basically I had been too lazy to write while loops over `std::copy`; You'll note that the changes (outside `readInto`) are minimal. _Note that with my dataset the benchmark got a bit skewed so I updated/extended the benchmark with a 'worst case' test as well_